# I'm having four errors coming from three lines about my arrays in a struct not being defined

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
     {
        int placer;
        int counter;
        srand(time(NULL));
        struct randoms;
        {
            int positive[50];
            int negative[50];
        }
        for (int countdown; countdown <= 999; countdown ++)
        {
            placer = rand() % (100 + 0) - 50;
            cout << placer << endl;
            if (placer < 0)
            {
                negative[placer] = negative[placer]++;
            cout << "doo doo head" << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                positive[placer] positive[placer]++;
            cout << "pee pee face" << endl;
            }
        }
        for (counter = 1; counter <=50; counter ++)
        {
        cout << counter << " appears " << negative[counter] << " times as a negative and      " << positive[counter] << " times as a positive." << endl;
        }
            return 0; 
        }
```

The offending lines are 29, 34, and 40
I can't figure out what I need to place if it's a header problem, or maybe my syntax is just really shitty. Right now I'm scratching my head on this one though.

Comment: Please copy and paste full error message you get.

Comment: Also, accessing array at index `-5` is not the best idea.

Comment: int countdown  may be initalize it with 0 ?

Comment: [Error] 'negative' was not declared in this scope

Comment: `positive[placer] positive[placer]++;` what's this? This makes no sense. This is no valid syntax. As for the `struct`, this makes no sense either. Just remove the `struct` so `int positive[50];` and `int negative[50];` are local variables.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that I didn't place the operand there. As far as the struct goes, that's currently the requirement of my assignment, but from what you have advised me, it looks like I may be using it in a less than useful method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct randoms;
{
    int positive[50];
    int negative[50];
}
```

is not a struct definition.
It's a declaration of a struct (defined elsewhere) followed by a block scope that declares two local variables.
These variables are unknown outside of that scope.

Perhaps you meant

```
struct
{
    int positive[50];
    int negative[50];
} randoms;
```

which declares a variable `randoms` of an unnamed struct type.

Or (this is more likely, as it is the more common use):

```
struct Randoms
{
    int positive[50];
    int negative[50];
};

int main()
{
    Randoms randoms;
    // ...
}
```

In any case, the struct members are `randoms.positive` and `randoms.negative`.
You must qualify the member names with the name of the variable.

Also,

```
negative[placer] = negative[placer]++;
```

should be one of

```
negative[placer]++;
```

or

```
negative[placer] += 1;
```

or

```
negative[placer] = negative[placer] + 1;
```

As a further note, you also need to initialise your arrays - if you don't, your program will have undefined behaviour.
(Doing it left as an exercise.)

Answer (score 1):

i think its because of some syntax error,i have tried to solve them:

```
                #include <iostream>
                #include <ctime>
                #include <cstdlib> 
                using namespace std; 

                int main() 
                    {
                        int placer;
                        int counter;
                        srand(time(NULL));
                        struct randoms{
                            int positive[50];
                            int negative[50];
                        } randoms;
                        for (int countdown; countdown <= 999; countdown ++)
                        {
                            placer = rand() % (100 + 0) - 50;
                            cout << placer << endl;
                            if (placer < 0)
                            {
                                randoms.negative[placer] = randoms.negative[placer]++;
                            std::cout << "doo doo head" << endl;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                randoms.positive[placer]=randoms.positive[placer]++;
                            cout << "pee pee face" << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        for (counter = 1; counter <=50; counter ++)
                        {
                        cout << counter << " appears " << randoms.negative[counter] << " times as a negative and      " << randoms.positive[counter] << " times as a positive." << endl;
                        }
                            return 0; 
                        }
```